How to draw this cutsom Arc/shape in Jetpack Compose Android

I am trying to draw this custom Arc/Progress bar in Jetpack Compose but all the custom shapes I found are drawArc or drawProgressBar but not the same shape I want.
I used the drawArc method but didn't work because the end of the arc was very close to the start.
@Composable
fun BTArc(arcSize: Dp) {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(arcSize)) {
        // Background Arc
        drawArc(
            color = Color.Yellow,
            140f,
            260f,
            false,
            style = Stroke(10.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
            size = Size(size.width, size.height)
        )

        // Foreground Arc
        drawArc(
            color = Color.Red,
            140f,
            200f,
            false,
            style = Stroke(10.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round),
            size = Size(size.width, size.height)
        )
    }
}

How to call it
BTArc(arcSize = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)

the final view I get


To draw an arch that fits a composable but drawn max in 180 degrees you need to set height 2 times of canvas to fit since Canvas height is height of 180 degrees arc.
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()) {
    val strokeWidth = 20.dp.toPx()
    translate(
        left = strokeWidth / 2,
        top = strokeWidth / 2
    ) {
        drawArc(
            color = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = .25f),
            size = Size(size.width - strokeWidth, (size.height - strokeWidth) * 2),
            startAngle = 180f,
            sweepAngle = 180f,
            style = Stroke(
                strokeWidth,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round
            ),
            useCenter = false
        )


        drawArc(
            color = Color.Blue,
            size = Size(size.width - strokeWidth, (size.height - strokeWidth) * 2),
            startAngle = 180f,
            sweepAngle = scale(0f, 1f, value, 0f, 180f),
            style = Stroke(
                strokeWidth,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round
            ),
            useCenter = false
        )
    }
}

And by using offset as stroke with you make sure that arc is drawn inside Canvas or Composable.

Demo
@Preview
@Composable
fun ArcTest() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(32.dp)
    ) {

        var value by remember {
            mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
        }

        Text("Value: ${(180 * value).toInt()}")

        Slider(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                value = it
            }
        )
        ArcSlider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(2f),
            value = value
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ArcSlider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: Float,
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()) {
            val strokeWidth = 20.dp.toPx()
            translate(
                left = strokeWidth / 2,
                top = strokeWidth / 2
            ) {
                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = .25f),
                    size = Size(size.width - strokeWidth, (size.height - strokeWidth) * 2),
                    startAngle = 180f,
                    sweepAngle = 180f,
                    style = Stroke(
                        strokeWidth,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round
                    ),
                    useCenter = false
                )


                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    size = Size(size.width - strokeWidth, (size.height - strokeWidth) * 2),
                    startAngle = 180f,
                    sweepAngle = scale(0f, 1f, value, 0f, 180f),
                    style = Stroke(
                        strokeWidth,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round
                    ),
                    useCenter = false
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Creating Arc Shaped Slider

First step is to create a Layout to contain track and thumb, measure thumb size, track size to be equal to Layout size and place thumb based on current angle calculated from value.
val strokeWidth = 20.dp

var angle by remember {
    mutableFloatStateOf(value * 180f)
}.apply { this.floatValue = value * 180f }


var thumbPosition by remember {
    mutableStateOf(Offset.Unspecified)
}

var thumbSize by remember {
    mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
}

var isTouched by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}

val measurePolicy = remember {
    MeasurePolicy { measurables, constraints ->

        val thumbPlaceable =
            measurables.fastFirst { it.layoutId == thumbId }.measure(
                constraints.copy(
                    minWidth = 0,
                    minHeight = 0
                )
            )
        val trackPlaceable = measurables.fastFirst { it.layoutId == trackId }.measure(constraints)

        val sliderWidth = trackPlaceable.width
        val sliderHeight = trackPlaceable.height

        val thumbWidth = thumbPlaceable.width
        val thumbHeight = thumbPlaceable.height

        val strokeWidthPx = strokeWidth.toPx()

        val radius = sliderWidth / 2
        val centerX = radius
        val centerY = sliderHeight
        val thumbX = centerX + (-radius + strokeWidthPx / 2) * cos(angle.degreeToRadian) - thumbWidth / 2
        val thumbY = centerY + (-radius + strokeWidthPx / 2) * sin(angle.degreeToRadian) - thumbHeight / 2
        thumbPosition = Offset(thumbX, thumbY)

        layout(sliderWidth, sliderHeight) {
            trackPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)

            if (thumbPosition != Offset.Unspecified) {
                thumbPlaceable.placeRelative(thumbPosition.x.toInt(), thumbPosition.y.toInt())
            }
        }
    }
} 

Step 2 checking if first touch position is inside thumb
onDragStart = { offset ->
    if (thumbPosition != Offset.Unspecified && thumbSize != IntSize.Zero) {
        val radius = thumbSize.width
        isTouched = offset.minus(thumbPosition).getDistanceSquared() < radius * radius
    }
},

Step 3 calculating angle based on user dragging
onDrag = { change: PointerInputChange, _: Offset ->
    if (isTouched) {
        val touchPosition: Offset = change.position
        val radius = size.width / 2
        val centerX = radius

        val centerY = size.height
        angle =
            (
                    atan2(
                        x = touchPosition.x.coerceIn(0f, size.width.toFloat())  - centerX,
                        y = touchPosition.y..coerceIn(0f, size.height.toFloat()) - centerY
                    )
                    ) * 180 / Math.PI.toFloat()


                            // If angle is in top half add 180 degrees since
                // atan2 returns angle between -PI and PI
                if (angle < 0) {
                    angle += 180f
                } else if (angle < 90) {
                    // If touch is bottom end set to 180f because it's out of slider bounds
                    angle = 180f
                } else {
                    // If touch is bottom end set to 0f because it's out of slider bounds
                    angle = 0f
                }


        onValueChange(scale(0f, 180f, angle, 0f, 1f))

    }
}

Full code
@Preview
@Composable
fun ArcSliderSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(32.dp)
    ) {
        var value by remember {
            mutableFloatStateOf(0f)
        }

        Box {
            ArcSlider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(2f),
                value = value
            ) {
                value = it
            }

            Text(
                text = "Value: ${(value * 100)}",
                fontSize = 28.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter).padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

private const val thumbId = "thumb"
private const val trackId = "track"

@Composable
fun ArcSlider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    thumb: @Composable () -> Unit = {
        Thumb()
    },
    value: Float,
    onValueChange: (Float) -> Unit,
) {

    val strokeWidth = 20.dp

    var angle by remember {
        mutableFloatStateOf(value * 180f)
    }.apply { this.floatValue = value * 180f }


    var thumbPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Unspecified)
    }

    var thumbSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
    }

    var isTouched by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val measurePolicy = remember {
        MeasurePolicy { measurables, constraints ->

            val thumbPlaceable =
                measurables.fastFirst { it.layoutId == thumbId }.measure(
                    constraints.copy(
                        minWidth = 0,
                        minHeight = 0
                    )
                )
            val trackPlaceable = measurables.fastFirst { it.layoutId == trackId }.measure(constraints)

            val sliderWidth = trackPlaceable.width
            val sliderHeight = trackPlaceable.height

            val thumbWidth = thumbPlaceable.width
            val thumbHeight = thumbPlaceable.height

            val strokeWidthPx = strokeWidth.toPx()

            val radius = sliderWidth / 2
            val centerX = radius
            val centerY = sliderHeight
            val thumbX = centerX + (-radius + strokeWidthPx / 2) * cos(angle.degreeToRadian) - thumbWidth / 2
            val thumbY = centerY + (-radius + strokeWidthPx / 2) * sin(angle.degreeToRadian) - thumbHeight / 2
            thumbPosition = Offset(thumbX, thumbY)

            layout(sliderWidth, sliderHeight) {
                trackPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)

                if (thumbPosition != Offset.Unspecified) {
                    thumbPlaceable.placeRelative(thumbPosition.x.toInt(), thumbPosition.y.toInt())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(2f)
                    .layoutId(trackId)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures(
                            onDragStart = { offset ->
                                if (thumbPosition != Offset.Unspecified && thumbSize != IntSize.Zero) {
                                    val radius = thumbSize.width
                                    isTouched = offset.minus(thumbPosition).getDistanceSquared() < radius * radius
                                }
                            },
                            onDrag = { change: PointerInputChange, _: Offset ->
                                if (isTouched) {
                                    val touchPosition: Offset = change.position
                                    val radius = size.width / 2
                                    val centerX = radius

                                    val centerY = size.height
                                    angle =
                                        (
                                                atan2(
                                                    x = touchPosition.x.coerceIn(0f, size.width.toFloat()) - centerX,
                                                    y = touchPosition.y.coerceIn(0f, size.height.toFloat()) - centerY
                                                )
                                                ) * 180 / Math.PI.toFloat()


                                    // If angle is in top half add 180 degrees since atan2 returns angle between -PI and PI
                                    if (angle < 0) {
                                        angle += 180f
                                    } else if (angle < 90) {
                                        // If touch is bottom end set to 180f because it's out of slider bounds
                                        angle = 180f
                                    } else {
                                        // If touch is bottom end set to 0f because it's out of slider bounds
                                        angle = 0f
                                    }

                                    onValueChange(scale(0f, 180f, angle, 0f, 1f))

                                }
                            },
                            onDragEnd = {
                                isTouched = false
                            },
                            onDragCancel = {
                                isTouched = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
            ) {
                Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    val strokeWidthPx = strokeWidth.toPx()
                    translate(
                        left = strokeWidthPx / 2,
                        top = strokeWidthPx / 2
                    ) {
                        drawArc(
                            color = Blue400.copy(alpha = .25f),
                            size = Size(size.width - strokeWidthPx, (size.height - strokeWidthPx) * 2),
                            startAngle = 180f,
                            sweepAngle = 180f,
                            style = Stroke(
                                strokeWidthPx,
                                cap = StrokeCap.Round
                            ),
                            useCenter = false
                        )

                        drawArc(
                            color = Blue400,
                            size = Size(size.width - strokeWidthPx, (size.height - strokeWidthPx) * 2),
                            startAngle = 180f,
                            sweepAngle = scale(0f, 1f, value, 0f, 180f),
                            style = Stroke(
                                strokeWidthPx,
                                cap = StrokeCap.Round
                            ),
                            useCenter = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            Box(modifier = Modifier.layoutId(thumbId)
                .onSizeChanged {
                    thumbSize = it
                }
            ) {
                thumb()
            }
        },
        measurePolicy = measurePolicy
    )
}

@Composable
private fun Thumb() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp).border(8.dp, Color.White, CircleShape)
            .shadow(4.dp, CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Blue, CircleShape)
    )
}

Scale function
// Scale x1 from a1..b1 range to a2..b2 range
internal fun scale(a1: Float, b1: Float, x1: Float, a2: Float, b2: Float) =
    lerp(a2, b2, calcFraction(a1, b1, x1))


// Calculate the 0..1 fraction that `pos` value represents between `a` and `b`
private fun calcFraction(a: Float, b: Float, pos: Float) =
    (if (b - a == 0f) 0f else (pos - a) / (b - a)).coerceIn(0f, 1f)


Thanks for your answer, It's worked for me but the challenge I have now the scale function you used is a custom one u make it?
scale(0f, 1f, value, 0f, 180f)

@AbdelrahmanAmer added scale function as well. lerp is from compose.util library. Also update this sample to add touch gesture on Layout instead of Canvas or track to be able to click each section of thumb while on 0 and 100. Full code is available here. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter6_graphics/Tutorial6_38ArcSlider.kt
